# Entity Framework Code First Optional Error Message

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, code-first

```
[Display(Name = "Mobile")]
public string Mobile { get; set; }
```

In the above code i want to include something like...

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="If you don't enter your email we cant send a text confirmation")]
```

However, i don't want to make the field required. Just if a user doesn't enter anything they get a message saying this. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: you can check conditin idf emailid == null then if you are using windows form Messagebox.show("your message") else continue your coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must write your own UI control to support this type of hint. It has nothing to do with common data annotations for validation and because of that you cannot use `Required`.